# How do you stop Azure Application Gateway creating new sessions every 30 seconds

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-gateway

I have a VM Scale Set setup behind a Azure Application Gateway which is load balancing web traffic between the 2 nodes in the scaleset which host a .net core web application.

We have session affinity turned off and have moved sessions to a redis distributed cache.

Now the problem is that every 30 seconds 2 new sessions gets created in the redis-cache. I believe this is the load balancer doing a health check. But since it creates 4 new sessions every minute, this becomes a problem since it fills upp redis.

How do you avoid this problem? Anyone facing a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to stop AppGW in creating new session as this is used for health probe purpose. You can increase the health probe interval appropriately such that the number of sessions will be less and also to make sure at the time of service failure the detection time is optimal.